# Restangular - Use custom methods with service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm using a [Decoupled Restangular service](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#decoupled-restangular-service) for consuming my API:

```
// Declare factory
module.factory('Users', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.service('users');
});
```

I'd like to call a custom method on my resource: `/users/active`
The documentation says I can do it like so:

```
// GET /users/active
Restangular.all("users").customGET("active")
```

However, I'd like to use the service I created before, rather than redeclaring a restangular resource 'users', which wouldn't be completely "DRY".

I'd like to do something like:

```
Users.customGET("active")
```

But I get an error TypeError: Users.customGET is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the with config try something like this

`return Restangular.withConfig(function(config){
        config.addElementTransformer('realm',true,function(worker){
          worker.addRestangularMethod('getActive','get');
            return worker;
        });
    }).service('users');`